# Task "Configure device connection string" is failing

Tags: iot-devkit

I am following the ["Get Started"](https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/get-started/) guide of the Microsoft IoT DevKit and I'm stuck on an annoying issue.

The step `Configure device connection string` keeps failing. I followed the tutorial step by step and everything worked fine before this precise step which is failing.

Basically, I run the task `config-device-connection`, I select the default, suggested string coming from my free trial account, I press the buttons following the combination and then I've got the error message `V Config IoT Hub device connection string: undefined`.

I had a look on Google and on the [Gitter Chat](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/azure-iot-developer-kit) but nobody seems to have had the same issue.

Thanks for your help !

Damien

Comment: Your edit should be posted and then marked as answer, not added to your question; that way, the question will not be left in a seemingly unanswered state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve my issue by myself. I followed the instructions [here](https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/use-configuration-mode/), especially the `set_az_iothubz` command and I was able to complete the tutorial.

Comment: I got the same error and was able to setup connection string manually using `screen` and `set_az_iothub`, but after upload my device still unable to connect to the iothub with `no iot hub` message. I'm following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-arduino-iot-devkit-az3166-translator . Did you face any similar issues after setting us the connection manually?

Comment: Hi @AlexeyStrakh, I didn't face any similar issue. However I was following a different tutorial [here](https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/get-started/), not sure if It's the same thing as you're trying to do.